# Scaling of a transition matrix

Tags: credit-ratings, markov, time-scale, transition-matrix

I am working on a ratings transition matrix and I wondered how people scale it down to shorter time periods (although one should more or less stick to the estimation period i know).

It is clear that one can scale it to a longer time period by repeatedly multiplying the matrix with itself.

How would you scale the matrix down to a, say monthly, transition matrix?

I found a result on *reversible* Markov Chains and thought the following:

Let $M$ be the transition matrix of a reversible markov chain, then one can factor it into
$$ M = S D$$

with a symmetric matrix $S$ and a diagonal matrix $D$. It appears that also the converse holds true.

Now, if we had a *reversible* markov chain, we could raise the matrix to a fraction by taking the eigenvalue decomposition of $S = E^{T}\Lambda E$ and raising $S$ as well as $D$ to the appropriate power.

So we define

$$ \bar{M}:= E^T \Lambda^{\frac{1}{n}}E D^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ and say that $\bar{M}$ is now $M^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

The question is: Is this way appropriate? Does it make any sense (from a mathematical viewpoint - I know that downscaling a transition matrix is debatable)? Are ratings transition matrices from a  *reversible* markov chain?

The main question is: What are the commonly used method to raise ratings transition matrices to a fraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the rules to time-scale a T-years transition matrix $M_T$ are:

- $M_{k·T} = M_T^k$
- $M_{T/k} = \sqrt[k]{M_T}$

The root of a matrix M can be obtained using the spectral decomposition:

$M = P·D·P^{-1} \Longrightarrow M^k = P·D^k·P^{-1}$

where $P$ and $D$ are the eigenvectors and eigenvalue matrices of $M_T$.

**Note**: The Perron-Frobenius tells that transition matrix eigenvalues satisfies |λ|≤1. This allows negative and complex eigenvalues. The following R code shows a transition matrix with a negative eigenvalue:

```
M = matrix(ncol=3, nrow=3, 0)
M[1,1]=0.1; M[1,2]=0.8; M[1,3]=0.1
M[2,1]=0.8; M[2,2]=0.1; M[2,3]=0.1
M[3,1]=0.0; M[3,2]=0.0; M[3,3]=1.0
eigen(M)
```

**Note**: As indicated in *[Regularization Algorithms for Transition Matrices](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Alexander_Kreinin/publication/215992315_Regularization_Algorithms_for_Transition_Matrices/file/d912f50d38c9e9ca02.pdf)*, the root of a transition matrix can be an invalid transition matrix or may not be unique. In this case, we must transform this matrix to the relevant Markov matrix. This process is called *regularization*. In the referenced document there exist some algorithms to regularize a transition matrix.

**Note**: I suspect that the transition matrices with a single absorbent state and strictly diagonal dominant has ​​real and positive eigenvalues, but I have no proof.

You can obtain more info at [CCruncher technical document](http://www.ccruncher.net/ccruncher.pdf).

Comment: Algorithms for computing these roots stably differ a bit from this approach.  Nick Higham does good work in this field.  Try [this paper](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/2021/01/covered/MIMS_ep2013_1.pdf)

Comment: @Gerard Torrent OK I think I am missing something: Why should the eigenvalues of $D$ be nonnegative or even real? Why should all fractional powers exist (like 1/12 for example)?

Comment: @BrianB Nice!! Now that I read it, the Schur decomposition looks like the natural approach for this...

Comment: @vanguard2k: I edited the entry trying to respond your question.

Comment: @Brian B: As I understand, the Schur-Pade algorithm obtains the same root matrix but with a superior accuracy. It can be usefull when the transition matrix is ill-conditioned.