# Through-the-cycle rating transition matrix

Tags: credit-risk, statistical-finance, econometrics, credit-ratings, transition-matrix

Suppose we know the observed transition matrix for annual migrations between credit ratings, $T_{ij,t}$, for $N$ years. **How is the through-the-cycle (TTC) transition matrix defined?**

Sometimes the following definition is used, just like other TTC quantities which are long-run averages (through a full economic cycle):
$$
\overline{T}_{ij} = \mathbb{E}(T_{ij,t})
$$

However, since the dynamics of credit rating migrations comes about by *multiplying* transition matrices, the above definition in terms of an *arithmetic mean* looks problematic in my opinion.

Shouldn't a more accurate definition be given in terms of the geometric mean?
$$
\overline{T} = \left(\prod_{t=1}^{N}(T_{t})\right)^{1/N}
$$
or, alternatively
$$
\overline{\log T} = \mathbb{E}(\log T_{t})
$$
Now, it is well known that taking logs and roots of transition matrices is fraught with non-uniqueness and non-positivity issues but there are some ways to tackle this -- there is some discussion [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10645/scaling-of-a-transition-matrix).

My question is what should be the correct definition of the through-the-cycle transition matrix? (For those who can relate, this question is similar to calculating quenched vs. annealed averages for disordered systems in physics.)